# C programming - Breaking down of money

Tags: c

I need to break down the amounts on their respective bill/coin.

The output is somewhat like this:

So far, here is my code: (I made the last few codes a comment one 'cos the 
errors come from there)

```
  { 
  int x,y;

  printf("Enter input: ");
  scanf("%d",&x);

  y=x/1000;
  printf("\n# of $1000 bill: %d",y);
  x = x%1000;

  y=x/500;      
  printf("\n# of 4500 bill: %d",y);    
  x = (x%500);

  y=x/200;
  printf("\n#. of $200 bill: %d",y);    
  x = (x%200);

  y=x/100;
  printf("\n# of $100 bill: %d",y);    
  x = (x%100);

  y=x/50;
  printf("\n# of $50 bill: %d",y);    
  x = (x%50);

  y=x/20;
  printf("\n# of $20 bill: %d",y);    
  x = (x%20);

  y=x/10;
  printf("\n#. of $10 coin: %d",y);    
  x = (x%10);

  y=x/5;
  printf("\n#. of $5 coin: %d",y);    
  x = (x%5);

  y=x/1;
  printf("\n# of $1 coin: %d",y);    
  x = (x%1);


  getch();
  return 0;
  }
```

I hope you'll help me out with this. :/

Thanks!

Comment: so what was the problem?

Comment: yes it is. the problem is, it doesn't work on the cents part.

Comment: I have removed the C++ tag. If a question is on C (as the title and code suggests) refrain from adding the c++ tag --C and C++ are different languages, and while most C code is proper C++ code in many cases good C++ solutions differ from the C version (even if that would compile in C++)

Comment: Note that this greedy solution works only if every bill value is greater than sum of values of "lesser" bills. Otherwise, you have to use dynamic programming.

Comment: Bunch of comments so far, also some solutions, however I still can't see anyone answer directly why you are getting compile errors. The answer is, C's modulo operator (`%`) is only defined between two integers, and `.25` and `.01` are floats. To avoid it, you can put it under a microscope, cut precisely while zoomed in, then zoom out again, metaphorically speaking: `((int)x * 100) % 25) / 100.0`

Comment: @Amadan I think you mean `(int)(x * 100) % 25) / 100.0`

Comment: rob2k8: To mark your question as answered, click the green check-mark next to the proper answer. Please don't remove your entire question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a simple heuristic problem. You already have the right idea. For a start, if you want to use int (and that's probably a good idea in your case to avoid fp-precision headaches and the need to use a separate fmod), you'll have to scale the floating-point input and your modulo/divisors by 100. Also to cut down on some redundancy, consider using a function like:

```
// returns number of units and subtracts unit_size * result
// from val
int units(int* val, int unit_size)
{
    int num = *val / unit_size;
    *val %= unit_size;
    return num;
}

printf("No. of P1000 bill: %d\n",units(&x, 1000 * 100) );
printf("No. of P500 bill: %d\n",units(&x, 500 * 100) );
printf("No. of P200 bill: %d\n",units(&x, 200 * 100) );
etc.
```

That should cut down on redundant code a little bit. Maybe not worth getting too fancy for it and I suspect this is homework. Complete solution:

```
// returns number of units and subtracts unit_size * result
// from val
int units(int* val, int unit_size)
{
    int num = *val / unit_size;
    *val %= unit_size;
    return num;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Enter input: ");

    float amount;
    scanf("%f",&amount);
    int x = (int)(amount * 100.0 + 0.5);

    printf("No. of P1000 bill: %d\n", units(&x, 1000 * 100) );
    printf("No. of P500 bill: %d\n", units(&x, 500 * 100) );
    printf("No. of P200 bill: %d\n", units(&x, 200 * 100) );
    printf("No. of P100 bill: %d\n", units(&x, 100 * 100) );
    printf("No. of P50 bill: %d\n", units(&x, 50 * 100) );
    printf("No. of P20 bill: %d\n", units(&x, 20 * 100) );
    printf("No. of P10 coin: %d\n", units(&x, 10 * 100) );
    printf("No. of P5 coin: %d\n", units(&x, 10 * 100) );
    printf("No. of P1 coin: %d\n", units(&x, 1 * 100) );
    printf("No. of 25 cents: %d\n", units(&x, 25) );
    printf("No. of 1 cent: %d\n", units(&x, 1) );

    return 0;
}
```

[Edit] If you have trouble understanding pointers, then just do it the way you wrote without using the units function but modify it accordingly to read in a float and multiply by 100 as in the example above.

[Edit] Requested:

```
int main()
{
    printf("Enter input: ");

    float amount;
    scanf("%f",&amount);
    int x = (int)(amount * 100.0 + 0.5); // x stores the user input in cents

    int y = x / 100000; // 1000 dollars is 100,000 cents
    printf("\nNo. of P1000 bill: %d",y);
    x = x % 100000;

    ...

    y=x / 25; // we're working with cents, so 25 = 25 cents
    printf("\nNo. of 25 cents: %d",y);    
    x = (x % 25);

    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 Good Answer... But change the pointer to reference to make it neat... (or move % out of the function)

Comment: The title and code suggests he's using C instead of C++ hence I avoided references in this case.

Comment: It has C++ tag... anyway you can just move % out of the function... he/she seems a beginner and may be confused with pointers..

Comment: Yeah, I added a comment at the bottom to just do it his way but modify it accordingly to convert to integer and scale by a hundred since there's little purpose using the units function otherwise. If he's using C++, he should probably use iostreams instead of printf/scanf as that doesn't require understanding format specifiers and pointer semantics on scanf.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's right to give the complete solution. You might like to read [How to ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/homework-on-stackoverflow).

Comment: @ChrisW Normally I'd refrain, but in the current situation, the original poster got it right logically with the exception of a lack of a solution for dealing with floating-point decimal units. Since he already did the bulk of the work, it's difficult to guide him in the right direction without a back-and-forth discussion format and easier to just provide a solution.

Comment: If this was a discussion, I'd point him to fmod, scaling the floating-point input to an integral, or reading it as a string and separating cents from dollars. I'd have to see if he needs additional help though; kind of difficult in this kind of format.

Comment: Okayy, I appreciate your help but I totally don't understand the functions or codes you've given. We are only required to use modulo and integer division (well, preferably) for now. And I don't get what you really meant on the edit message of yours. I hope you'll help me in solving this. :/

Comment: @rob2k8 in that case, you can ignore everything I wrote with the exception of this part: float amount; scanf("%f",&amount); int x = (int)(amount * 100.0); Those three lines are required so that the user can type in a floating-point value but so that you can still perform all the division using integer division and modulo. You will have to scale all your unit sizes by 100 (ex: P200 bill should be 200 * 100 or 20000) so that they're all integrals representing cents.

Comment: Okay. I have this code. My problem is on how do I change the cents in my modulo. Do I still need to scale it by 100? If so, how? 'Cos I've tried having x=(x*100)%(5*100) won't work on any of the bill/coin/cents. It gives another answer. BTW, here's my code in the last part:

      y=(100*x)/(1*100);
      printf("\nNo. of P1 coin: %d",y);    
      x = (x%1);
           
      y=(100*x)/(25);
      printf("\nNo. of 25 cents: %d",y);    
      x = x%(25); //this part. How do I edit this? It gives me error
when I try to make it (25/100) or (0.25)

Comment: Can you give me the actual coding of it at least 'til 500 or 200 with my code that is added by the 3 lines you said? I have that idea but I'm always lost when I try. Please :/

Comment: I added an edit with a couple of examples which should set you on the right track. Just fill in the missing parts.

Comment: I now got it but I have a mathematical error on the 1 cent part. When I try to input other numbers, it works well. But when I input the amount "4654.46", I got a result of 20 instead of 21. But when I try on 5 digits (54302.46), it gives the right amount which is 21. So maybe it doesn't work on 4 digits but it is required on our homework to make it work on 4 digits as well. BTW, the edited code is written above.

Comment: @rob2k8: fixed in the example above. See the line where we define 'x'.

Answer (score 2):

Scan the user's value into a `float`, then separate the dollars and cents into two `int` values.

The coins required for the cents value should then be very easy to calculate, using the same method you've already used (except dividing/mod by 25 for 25 cents, 1 for 1 cent etc.)

Comment: oho, many issues come with code using floats (rounding problems) I would not advice anyone to do that, rather use integers * 100.

Comment: I'm only recommending receiving the user's input using a float. From there all calculations are done on ints.

The highest rated solution in this thread also receives the user's value into a float. Why is his fine while mine is not?

Comment: Matthew, I must confess that I misunderstood the answer by reading it too quickly. But just for your info, I did not downrate you. I will give you an upvote as soon as I get some votes again (means tomorrow). Don't give up, getting downvotes is quite discouraging sometimes, I know it from my own experience, I had to learn not taking it too personal. Go on and you'll succeed! :-) Sometimes people get influenced by the comments below the answer, maybe I am indirectly responsible for the -1, sorry...

Comment: "Why is his fine while mine is not?" -- I think your answer is better: because yours clearly and concisely describes the algorithm/method (without giving the code); so +1.

Comment: Matthew, I'm sorry. I don't get your point to use the same method except for dividing/mod by 25 for 25 cents? So what am I supposed to do with the 25 cents part?

Comment: @rob2k8 - After you've stored the fractional cents in an integer (by multiplying by 100), then change your code to use `25` instead of `0.25`.

Comment: @Matthew: the +1 you deserved! :-)